# Erro em calculadora criada no android studio

Tags: java, android

Comecei a fazer algumas coisas com no android studio. O erro que está dando é em uma calculadora simples e que não faz as operações corretas, exemplo: 1+2=1,1+8=1, e outras que ficam dando 0.
Tenho dois `textview`, operação e resultado, e 16 botoes incluindo números e as quatro operações. Aparecem todos no aplicativo, e quando clico aparece todos os sinais, só as operações que saem incorretas.

Segue o código da calculadora:

```
package com.example.familia.isabellyemmanuelly;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calculadora extends Activity {

    TextView textOperacao;
    TextView textResultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculadora);

        textOperacao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_operacao);
        textOperacao.setText("");

        textResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_resultado);
        textResultado.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calculadora, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void clickOne(View view){

        textOperacao.append("1");
    }

    public void clickTwo(View view){

        textOperacao.append("2");
    }

    public void clickThree(View view){

        textOperacao.append("3");
    }

    public void clickFour(View view){

        textOperacao.append("4");
    }

    public void clickFive(View view){

        textOperacao.append("5");
    }

    public void clickSix(View view){

        textOperacao.append("6");
    }

    public void clickSeven(View view){

        textOperacao.append("7");
    }

    public void clickEight(View view){

        textOperacao.append("8");
    }

    public void clickNine(View view){

        textOperacao.append("9");
    }

    public void clickZero(View view){

        textOperacao.append("0");
    }

    public void clickSum(View view){

        textOperacao.append(" + " );
    }

    public void clickSubtract(View view){

        textOperacao.append(" - ");
    }

    public void clickMultiply(View view){

        textOperacao.append(" x ");
    }

    public void clickDivide(View view){

        textOperacao.append(" / ");
    }

    public void clickC(View view){

        textOperacao.setText("");
        textResultado.setText("");
    }

    public void clickResult(View view){

        String operation = textOperacao.getText().toString();
        String[] components = operation.split(" ");

        if(components.length == 3) {

            double numero1 = (double) Integer.parseInt(components[0]);
            String sinal = components[1];
            double numero2 = (double) Integer.parseInt(components[2]);

            if(sinal.equals("+"))
                textResultado.setText( String.format("%.0f", (numero1 + numero2)) );

            if(sinal.equals("-"))
                textResultado.setText( String.format("%.0f", (numero1 - numero2)) );

            if(sinal.equals("x"))
                textResultado.setText( String.format("%.0f", (numero1 * numero2)) );

            if(sinal.equals("/")) {

                if( numero1 % numero2 != 0 )
                    textResultado.setText( String.format("%.2f", (numero1 / numero2)) );
                else textResultado.setText( String.format("%.0f", (numero1 / numero2)) );
            }
        }
        else textResultado.setText( "Operação não reconhecida :(" );
    }

}
```

Comment: Posta o trecho do código que captura os números e faz as operações, antes que comecem a negativar sua pergunta por falta de conteúdo e para que possamos saber o que está errado.

Comment: coloquei o código ai,Irmao

Comment: os botões são 2 mediumtextview para resultado e operação
1-9
e os operadores " + ", " - ", " * ", " / "

Comment: Tente usar String.valueOf(numero1 + numero2) para extrair o resultado da operação de soma, o mesmo para as outras operações

Comment: if(components.length == 3) {

            double numero1 = (double) Integer.parseInt(components[0]);
            String sinal = components[1];
            double numero2 = (double) Integer.parseInt(components[2]);

fiz assim e deu certo ....vlw Irmao___________________________________________________
double numero1 = Double.valueOf(components[0]).doubleValue();
            String sinal = components[1];
            double numero2 = Double.valueOf(components[2]).doubleValue();

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente não implementaria uma calculadora como você está fazendo. Utilizaria duas pilhas uma para operandos e outra para operadores e, manipulando essas duas pilhas, teria os resultados mais performáticos do que "parsear" strings para tirar operações.

Caso decida continuar a implementar neste modelo, no seu clickResult, chame este método, passando toda a string, semelhante a que você mostra no display para o usuário. Esse código está disponível e foi citado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

```
public static double eval(final String str) {
    return new Object() {
        int pos = -1, ch;

        void nextChar() {
            ch = (++pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
        }

        boolean eat(int charToEat) {
            while (ch == ' ') nextChar();
            if (ch == charToEat) {
                nextChar();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        double parse() {
            nextChar();
            double x = parseExpression();
            if (pos < str.length()) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            return x;
        }

        // Grammar:
        // expression = term | expression `+` term | expression `-` term
        // term = factor | term `*` factor | term `/` factor
        // factor = `+` factor | `-` factor | `(` expression `)`
        //        | number | functionName factor | factor `^` factor

        double parseExpression() {
            double x = parseTerm();
            for (;;) {
                if      (eat('+')) x += parseTerm(); // addition
                else if (eat('-')) x -= parseTerm(); // subtraction
                else return x;
            }
        }

        double parseTerm() {
            double x = parseFactor();
            for (;;) {
                if      (eat('*')) x *= parseFactor(); // multiplication
                else if (eat('/')) x /= parseFactor(); // division
                else return x;
            }
        }

        double parseFactor() {
            if (eat('+')) return parseFactor(); // unary plus
            if (eat('-')) return -parseFactor(); // unary minus

            double x;
            int startPos = this.pos;
            if (eat('(')) { // parentheses
                x = parseExpression();
                eat(')');
            } else if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') { // numbers
                while ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') nextChar();
                x = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(startPos, this.pos));
            } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // functions
                while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') nextChar();
                String func = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
                x = parseFactor();
                if (func.equals("sqrt")) x = Math.sqrt(x);
                else if (func.equals("sin")) x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x));
                else if (func.equals("cos")) x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
                else if (func.equals("tan")) x = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(x));
                else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            }

            if (eat('^')) x = Math.pow(x, parseFactor()); // exponentiation

            return x;
        }
    }.parse();
}
```